# How to insert data into multiple tables in one query

Tags: users

I created custom user registration form. the data get saved in the user table as required but the others field like fname,mobile and address are not getting saved in the following tables.
1. table name- field_data_field_name
  field name- field_fname_value

2. table name- field_data_field_mobile
   field name- field_mobile_value
3. table name- field_data_field_address
   field name- field_address_value

unfortunately i am not aware of how to insert data into three different table.so please help me with the solution for the same

i create another user registration from.the standard registration form is for doctor so they have different fields. this registration form is only for user to save basic information like address,fname and mobile number.this 3 fields are same as standard form fields.so thats why i want to insert this data into those tables.please help me

```
  function register_form($form,&$form_state) 
     {
     $form = array();

    $form['name'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Username',
    '#description' => 'choose a username',
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
     );

    $form['mail'] = array(
    '#title' => 'email',
    '#description' => 'enter a valid email address',
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,

    );

     $form['fname'] = array(
        '#title' => 'Full Name',
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => TRUE,
     );

     $form['mobile'] = array(
        '#title' => 'Mobile',
        '#description' => 'Mobile',
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => TRUE,

      );  
       $form['address'] = array(
        '#title' => 'Address',
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => TRUE,
      );

    $form['submit'] = array(
    '#value' => 'Submit',
    '#type' => 'submit'
    ); 
    return $form;
    }

    function register_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
   $pass=user_password();

   $account = array(
  'name' => $form_state['values']['name'],
  'pass' => $pass,
  'mail' => $form_state['values']['mail'],
  'init' => $form_state['values']['mail'],
  'status' => 1,
  'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
  );
  user_save(drupal_anonymous_user(), $account);
  }
```

Comment: Why would you do that? What's wrong with using three queries?

Comment: Are you aware that you can add fields to user registration form and not create another one? And are you aware that Drupal inserts automatically the data where they should be in the DB?

Comment: ya but i create another user registration from.the standard registration form is for doctor so they have different fields. this registration form is only for user to save basic information like address,fname and mobile number.this 3 fields are same as standard form fields.so thats why i want to insert this data into those tables.please help me.

Comment: not find right answer till now.

Answer (score 1):

It is **impossible**. Drupal uses MySQL by default, and [MySQL's INSERT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) requires one and only one table name.

In theory you could use PostgreSQL and it's [triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html) - create a view from these 3 tables, and in insert trigger of that view perform inserts to underlying tables, but it wouldn't be universal solution, and I can't think of any particular reason to do it in one query anyway. If you need to ensure data consistency, [DatabaseTransaction](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/class/DatabaseTransaction/7) is the way.